# (Bash, terminal) why do killing script hotkeys don't work (e.g. ctrl-c, ctrl-z)

Tags: linux, bash, signals, hotkeys

when i try to kill the script by ctrl-z or ctrl-c they are interpreted like input and not commands.
I'm using linux (fedora 37) on a virtual box machine

terminal:

```
[me@meVPC ~]$ ./time_logger
9698
^C
^C
^Z
```

the script:
`

```
#!/bin/bash

log_file="time_log.txt"
signal_script="script_logger"

# Start the signal script
bash $signal_script &

# Function to send signals
send_signal() {
    signal=$1
    pkill -RTMIN+$signal -f $signal_script

}

# Signal handling
trap 'send_signal 2' SIGINT   # Signal for script stop
trap 'send_signal 3' SIGTSTP   # Signal for script pause
trap 'send_signal 4'  SIGCONT  #signal for script continue

send_signal 1               #sending signal that script started
echo $$                      #showing PID of this process

while true
    do
    current_time=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    echo "$current_time" >> $log_file
    sleep 60
done`
```

i tried killing it from another bash terminal window, strangely it works half the times.

Comment: C-Z is a SIGSTOP. You're capturing SIGSTOP. Ctrl+C is a SIGINT. You're capturing SIGINT. So the signals don't have normal/default behavior for your program _because you're explicitly overriding them_.

Comment: so, if I understand correctly, when i capture SIGINT and override it, I also have to explicitely write in my script to exit (if I want it to) ? And if i don't, my captured SIGINT is just gonna do some other stuff without actually killing my script?

Comment: Right, when you trap SIGINT, you're _replacing_ its default behavior so it no longer does what it would have done by default.

Comment: (btw, my close vote was cast back before you replaced the images with text -- my apologies for not getting it retracted; should have reversed it as soon as I saw you'd made the question self-contained and clearly about code as opposed to about shell/terminal behavior)

Comment: my bad, I clearly should have read the rules _before_ writing the question

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it's reopened now if you were considering posting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you `trap` a signal, that doesn't just add extra behavior *before* the signal is handled -- it outright *replaces* the default signal handler.

Thus, the `trap 'send_signal 2' SIGINT` prevents ctrl+C from having its default behavior, and the `trap 'send_signal 3' SIGSTP` prevents ctrl+Z from having its default behavior.